# How to get a video in the middle of a page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website which is similar to this https://www.netflix.com/in/title/80189221. I would like to know how to get the video in the middle of the page. 
My code looks like this.

```
iframe {
    width:240px;
    height:160px;
    align: middle;
 }
```

I've also tried this:

```
iframe {
    width:240px;
    height:160px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: add position: absolute; in the last iframe css, hope it'll work!

Comment: please add html code also. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to the `iframe`

```css
.ifrmae-holder {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ifrmae-holder">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E4n7BQkOQ_s" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be aligned at the middle of the page and not the centre. Something like this[link](https://www.netflix.com/in/title/80189221).

Comment: @Fibonaccifreak should use `position`

Answer (score 0):

> **I think this is the easy way to center any content**

[**js fiddle example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/razibmahmud50/q1a9urtd/)

```css
.ifrmae-holder {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ifrmae-holder">
<iframe width="300" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E4n7BQkOQ_s" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```